# Set as default / Set to default?

Tags: word-choice

Here's a pretty simple question, but one that I couldn't figure out.
Is something said to be *Set as default* or *Set to default*?
For example, a line on a form with a checkbox.

Which way should it read?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.

If you want to set the current value as the default value, for future use or something else, *set as default* would be the correct text.

If you mean, to set the current value to the default value (i.e. changing it to some other, previously specified or natural default value) then *set to default* would be what you require.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the math way.

Set as default = What you see on the screen RIGHT NOW, will become the new setting.

Set to default = What the device was set to initially by the manufacturer or programmer (or last teacher, lol) will be restored.